# git - push file to one remote only

Tags: git

I have one git-repository that gets pushed to two remotes. The first remote, `A`, is "public" accessible, but the second one, `B`, is accessible to selected persons only.

Now I have one file that I don't want to be public. Therefore I'd like to push it to remote `B` only.

I could simply add the "secret" file to the repository and push to `B` only. But then the file is already added to my local git-repository. The next time I change something in another file and push to `A` the "secret" file would be pushed too.

Is there a (simple) way to solve this problem?

Comment: Maybe git submodules can be a solution for this? I have never worked with it before tho

Comment: Note that any file in a Git repository is quite *non*-secret and viewable by anyone who has that repository. In any case, repositories do not directly contain *files*, but rather *commits* (and then commits refer to files which is how you wind up finding them, at least normally, but again someone who has the repository can find any file anywhere within it through maintenance commands).

Answer (score 1):

You could have a different branch which contains this file, and only push that branch to your private repository.

Of course, you'll have to keep it up to date with the `master` branch with `rebase` or `merge` by yourself.